# XML listview issue

Tags: java, android

Trying to set a listview up with the results of my database query.

Anyway, I'm getting a weird XML refrence id error from my listview. Can anyone see the issue here? Im guessing its the '@id' reference causing the problem?

Heres my XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/contentList"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
</ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

And my java class:

The error is on the 'R.id.conactList'.

```
ListView listContent = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.contentList);
```

Comment: You are missing a lot of relevant information (Stack Trace, where you are calling findViewById, the class the call in made from, why you're using `id.contactList` instead of `id.contentList`, etc), but I am gonna guess that you failed to set the content view of your Activity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks good to me.  You can change `></ListView>` to `/>` to clean up the xml just a bit.  Try cleaning your project to make sure your R file is getting updated.  Is there log you can post?  What exactly is the error?

Comment: Hi James. Ive cleaned it a number of times. The actual, error is on the 'contentList' reference and the error is described as 'Layout cannot be resolved, or is not a field'.

Comment: Make sure you are importing the `R.java` file from your package and not some other package like `android`.  Can you investigate your R file and check if `contactList` is defined there?